# Primes of the form $10^n + 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was just playing with $10^n + 1$, and the I realize that I found only 3 of them ($n=0,1,2$)

I was wondering whether there's another $n$ in which $10^n + 1$ is prime, or is this not yet known? 
My limited programming skill only check up to $n = 30$

Comment: For composite $n \ge 3$, the number $10^n+1$ is not prime. If $a$ divides $n$, then $10^a+1$ divides $10^n+1$.

Comment: What about when $n$ is prime?

Comment: Another prime of this form must be huge since $n$ must be a power of two and small factors are known upto a very large limit.

Comment: So, not yet known?

Comment: [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=10%5E2%5En%2B1&use=n&n=0&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&FF=on&PRP=on&CF=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=25&format=1) you can look zp the factorizations of $10^{2^k}+1$. The smallest unknown case is $k=21$ , so another prime of this form must have at least $2$ million digits, so I am pretty sure that no other prime of this form is known.

Comment: @Crostul Don't you mix this with the generlized Mersenne numbers ? If $n$ is an odd prime , then $10^n+1$ is divisible by $11$

Comment: @Peter I think the pieces of information you shared already give everything that the community knows, so might make an adequate answer? I would be delighted to be proven wrong as I know very little, but anyway :-)

Comment: $11$ and $101$ are the only prime terms up to $n=100000$ (see https://oeis.org/A000533)

Comment: [this](http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN10.html) is an even better site : It states that the smallest unknown case is $k=31$ , so another prime of this form would be far far larger than the largest known prime. It seems that there is almost no hope to find another prime of this form.